# Glide issues on re opening + cannot load from destroyed activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-glide

I've been using Glide in adapter where I pass context from Activity class to my fragment(View is in fragment). I've checked in around 30 devices and in 3-5 devices app crashes when the user tries to restart after closing. What could be the reason and how to handle this exception?
I don't want to use Applicationcontext in Glide as this will keep the glide resources. Is there any other workaround?

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:134)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:102)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
at com.trial.project.Adapter.LiveUserListAdapterInside.onBindViewHolder(LiveUserListAdapterInside.java:68)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1618)
```

**Below code for glide loading**

```
Glide.with(itemHolder.ImageView.getContext())
    .load( current.getPhotoUrl() )
    .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(context))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.x2)
    .into(itemHolder.friendImageView);
```

**Below code for OnBackPressed()**

```
    // ... ...
      ... ..
    finishAffinity();
```

Comment: add logcat please .

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have the specific logcat of those devices and we cannot recreate the error in our official test devices either but it was something like stated below and occured in the line of Glide.load...

   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Comment: I've added logcat @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: please check now @Anonymous

Comment: @user232803..yes I got the issue..I already posted the solution know..Your activity tends to get destroyed by the time image is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are trying to load an image I guess the activity wil be in destroyed state.This happens when you try to load an image and move to different activity before loading.So make a null check to see if still activity exists and also image reference exists.

Also replace itemHolder.ImageView.getContext() with itemHolder.friendImageView.getContext().

Check this edited code for loading image

```
 if(!this.isDestroyed() && friendImageView!=null && current.getPhotoUrl()!=null){
        Glide.with(itemHolder.friendImageView.getContext())
                .load( current.getPhotoUrl())
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(context))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.x2)
                .into(itemHolder.friendImageView);  
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear about this 'itemHolder.ImageView.getContext() with itemHolder.ImageView.getContext()'. will be checking for null though

Comment: sorry it was friendImageView.The context is creating nullPointerexception.Either us that or use getApplicationContext() or

Comment: Also if !this.isDestroying() isnt working !this.isFinishing() should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Always use the `Activity context` while loading images using Glide.

And while using Glide with `adapters` you can pass `RequestManager` object from activity itself in Constructor of `adapter` using `Glide.with(this)`.

It is always safe to check whether `activity/fragment` is visible or not before starting a Glide load.

So for Activity :

```
if(!this.isFinishing()){
   // Initialise Glide here
}
```

For Fragment :

```
MyFragmentClass mFragment = (MyFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("testID");
if (mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible()) {
     // Initialise Glide here
}
```

Ref : https://android.jlelse.eu/using-glide-few-tips-to-be-a-pro-60f41e29d30a

Comment: how about recyclerViewAdapter?